# How can I get Windows 7 firewall to stop changing settings?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, firewall

I keep getting the stupid notifications about programs I've allowed in the firewall manually. I have tried , Netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off, and , Netsh firewall mode = disable profile = all. They both work for about 10~15 sec until Windows changes my setting. I've ran them both in elevated cmd's and my setting will not stay the same. Is there a way I can keep Windows Firewall enabled but just get rid of all notifications?